# Accordion Inside Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, accordion

I am using Organic Tabs ([here](http://css-tricks.com/organic-tabs/)) on my page. They look great and I am happy with the way they work...mostly. I am running into an issue where I have a vertical accordion inside one of my tabs and the size of the div is not adjusting with the accordion opening/closing.

When I load the page, the div height is not set in the CSS, so the accordion works (since it is on the first tab). But then when I switch tabs the size of the div is recalculated to a fixed height, which is where the problem occurs.

I am trying to find a way to clear the inline styles when that tab is clicked, I have tried:

```
$allListWrap.css('height', "auto !important");
```

and a whole bunch of other syntax, and it just doesn't seem to work. When I set it this way, I just keeps the size of the previous tab and doesn't resize. Any suggestions on how to set the height to auto when the tab is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Try and get rid of the `!important`. You can't declare important with jQuery so it's probably not changing it because of that.

EDIT: you can call important, however, you have to call it like this `jQuery('#id').css('cssText', 'height: 200px !important');`